# How to convert a dynamic string to bitmap?

Tags: android, string, bitmap

I'd like to convert a dynamic string to Bitmap and save it on disk. The image should appear like the image below with the corner around the string.
I couldnt find a way to direct convert a String to bitmap, I tried to create a textView and convert it to bitmap, but it dont work properly.

Obs: I saw some questions that is similar, but they really don't have a solution to this question.

[image]

```
public static String StringToBitMap(Context context, String name){


        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText(name);
        try{
            int w = textView.getWidth();
            int h = textView.getHeight();
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            Drawable bgDrawable = textView.getBackground();
            if (bgDrawable!=null)  {
                bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
            }
            else {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            textView.draw(canvas);

            FileOutputStream out = null;
            File file = null;
            try {
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                file = new File(path + "/Download/", "item.png");
                out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
                // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
                out.close();

                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }



            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution:

```
public static String StringToBitMap(Context context, String name){

        try{
            // Create bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(250, 16,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            canvas.drawColor(0xffffffff);

            // new antialised Paint
            Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            // text color - #3D3D3D
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            // text size in pixels
            paint.setTextSize(12);
            // draw text to the Canvas center
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            paint.getTextBounds(name, 0, name.length(), bounds);
            int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width())/2;
            int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height())/2;

            canvas.drawText(name, x, y, paint);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            // draw corner to the Canvas
            canvas.drawRect(x - 5, 0.0f, x + bounds.width() + 5, 16.0f, paint);

            // save on disk
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            File file = null;
            try {
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                file = new File(path + "/Download/", "item.png");
                out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
                // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
                out.close();

                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }



            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
```